# How to get a variable from a list inside a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, bigdata

I have a data like this;

```
{"result": [{"name": "Mil", "age": 21, "id": 1}, {"name": "Jen", "age": 23, "id": 2}, {"name": "Rosa", "age": 26, "id": 3}]}
```

How can I get just the 'age' value of each individual from a data like this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the ages like this:

```py
d = {"result": [{"name": "Mil", "age": 21, "id": 1}, {"name": "Jen", "age": 23, "id": 2}, {"name": "Rosa", "age": 26, "id": 3}]}
ages = [res["age"] for res in d["result"]]  # [21, 23, 26]
```

Indeed, `d["result"]` is a list of dicts. So, in a more expanded form, it is the same as:

```py
d = {"result": [{"name": "Mil", "age": 21, "id": 1}, {"name": "Jen", "age": 23, "id": 2}, {"name": "Rosa", "age": 26, "id": 3}]}

results = d["result"]  # a list
ages = []
for res in results:
    age = res["age"]
    ages.append(age)

print(ages)  # [21, 23, 26]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can this code:

```
dic={"result": [{"name": "Mil", "age": 21, "id": 1}, {"name": "Jen", "age": 23, "id": 2}, {"name": "Rosa", "age": 26, "id": 3}]}
lst = dic["result"]
age_lst =[]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    age =lst[i]["age"]
    age_lst = [age]+age_lst
print(age_lst)
```